# How to resolve HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web application. It runs well on developing mode (Windows10 VS 2022), but when I publish it to IIS, I get this below error:

[image]

I tried to add this `web.config` file to my project:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But then I get this error:

[image]

And in the Windows Event viewer, I see this error:

> Application '/LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT' with physical root 'D:\publish' failed to start process with commandline '"%LAUNCHER_PATH%" %LAUNCHER_ARGS%' with multiple retries. Failed to bind to port '44162'. First 30KB characters of captured stdout and stderr logs from multiple retries:

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

The path %LAUNCHER_PATH% was not exist on my system, it was not even valid.

so I changed this line:

```
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

to this:

```
    <aspNetCore processPath="%.\myappname.exe%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

**and the problem has been solved!**